# The arm board has no reaction to .bin file

Tags: arm, embedded, u-boot, openocd

everyone, I am a beginner of embedded system programming, my first led test program for my board, which is mini2440, was written in assembly language as .S file:

```html
.text
.global _start
_start:
 bl disable_watch_dog        
 ldr r0, =0x56000010         
 mov r1, #0x15400            
 str r1, [r0]

 ldr r0, =0x56000018        
 mov r1, #0x0
 str r1, [r0]

 ldr r0, =0x56000014        
MAIN_LOOP:                         
 mov r1, #0x0               
 str r1, [r0]
 mov r2, #0x50000
 bl delay                   

 mov r1, #0x1e0             
 str r1, [r0]
 mov r2, #0x50000
 bl delay
 b MAIN_LOOP

disable_watch_dog:
 ldr r0, =0x53000000
 mov r1, #0x0
 str r1, [r0]
 mov pc, r14                
delay:
 sub r2, r2, #0x1
 cmp r2, #0x0
 bne delay
 mov pc, lr
```

After the compiling I got .bin file from this program and I wrote it to the band flash of mini2440 with opened:

```html
telnet localhost 4444
halt
init_2440
nand erase 0 0x0 0x100000
nand write 0 /home/led/led.bin 0
reset
```

I did not see any error or warning from the terminal but the board just has no reaction, all the leds were dark. I appreciate it if anyone could explain me about this.
Thanks

Comment: try a simpler program.  set the led gpio pin(s), and go into an infinite loop.  then do a second test, reset/zero the led gpio pin(s) and go into an infinite loop.  each program disables watchdog if required, enables the gpio block, and either sets or resets the gpio pin in question, but does not attempt to blink it.  set in case that turns the led on (read your schematic), then infinite loop so it doesnt change the led.   if that doesnt turn on and leave on the led, then try again but reset the gpio pin this time, infinite loop, no blink, see if th eled comes on.

Comment: if you cant force the led on or off and leave it that way then there is no way you can blink it.

Comment: Without knowing what state the device is left in by the bootloader, it is not possible to tell whether this code has even a chance of running - it relies on an a significant amount of processor initialisation, such as clock, peripheral and MMU configuration.  I would not even start on such a processor without a hardware debugger, and I would not assume any specific initialisation by the bootloader, and perform all necessary start-up code in the application itslelf - even if already done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have a Jtag hardware debugger, the code was written into the board with it in openocd, and when I started init_2440 in openocd, there was one led which was lighted, I haven't installed the GDB yet, so I didn't run it with debugger, just wrote it to nand flash.

Comment: By the way, the board used to have bootloader in nand flash, but I have erased it and tested the led with bare board.

Comment: if you have the debugger you can simply write/read these registers by hand (mdw, mww in openocd) and see if you can turn the led on or see if the gpio is responding or see if the arm hangs (indicating you touched a clock domain that didnt have the clocks enabled and/or was in reset).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used init_2440 function from openocd and I saw that one led was lighted, seemed ok, but when I wrote the program into the board, the board had no reaction, will run another test today and update the situation tomorrow, thank all of you, all information is helpful

Comment: Thanks for the comment of old_timer, I did the same test with openocd, the board reacted to the mww command, but it did not react to the .bin file, my board was a total bare board, without system, without boot loader, so this led program needs boot loader to run or something wrong happened when I wrote the .bin file to the board?